# Javascript replacement of sourceIndex in chromium browsers

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom

I am currently rewriting some parts of an older system to work on the newest chromium browsers.
However, some parts of the system relied on old browser-specific code, such as the .sourceIndex attribute in the old Internet Explorer, which is deprecated now.

I have the following code, that is supposed to sort all the elements of the array based on the index of which they appear in the document.

```js
arrReturnElements.sort(function (a, b) { // Perform a sort of all elements
    return (a.sourceIndex < b.sourceIndex ? -1 : (b.sourceIndex < a.sourceIndex ? 1 : 0));
});
```

I have quite a few different elements in my document, so I need a generalizable method that can efficiently calculate the index.

Can you help with an optimal way of performing this sort in javascript?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason if the `sourceIndex` was deprecated. I will suggest you a workaround, even if it's very slow:

```
const allElements = Array.from(document.all);
const arrReturnElementsPatched = arrReturnElements.map(element => 
 ({ sourceIndex: allElements.indexOf(element), ...element})
);
```

Then use `arrReturnElementsPatched` in place of `arrReturnElements`.

But I seriously advise you to refactor your code in order to achieve the result without the use of `document.all` and `sourceIndex`. For example, you can check if ordering by the index in array will have the same output. Or if, after all, this sorting is actually needed.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution. And it appears to perform the sorting exactly as I need it currently, while also surprisingly fast. I can not feel any performance impact.

I know a refactoring is severely needed, but for now, I needed a solution that just works.
Thank you very much for the answer, it was perfect!

Comment: @ThorvaldJørgensen Maybe it doesn't impact the performance now, in your browser, on your machine, and on your page. But `Array.from(document.all)` can be really large, `indexOf` performs a search and if you repeat it for several items, the performance can easily degrade. So here you have your code, but I wouldn't advise it :)

Comment: Alright, I understand.
I will try some scenarios to test the performance impact on our system. 
Thanks for the advice :)